# Installing bluetooth module on Dell Precision M4600

Tags: installation, bluetooth, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision M4600 without a Bluetooth module (Bios says unavailable). I'm thinking about buying and installing [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/300776864127)

I have two questions

1. Does [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/300776864127) work on Dell M4600?
2. How can I install it?

Comment: The ad says it does, what more do you need to know? [Download the Owners Manual here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/precision-m4600/manuals)

Comment: @Moab Thank you! Just wasn't sure if M4600's that don't come with a factory bluetooth module have the necessary ports/terminals/connections in the laptop to add the module.